# Why pandas cannot read correctly a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to read data from a .csv file into a pandas dataframe. I have the very simple code:

```
import pandas as pd 

file_name = "C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/Results.csv"
df = pd.read_csv (file_name, sep=',')
print(df)
```

The file contains one single line: the header:

```
Publication,First Name,Last Name,Constituency,Caucus,Province,Date,Time,Page,Text
```

and the above code dispalys:

```
P   Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7  Unnamed: 8  Unnamed: 9
```

So, it looks like pandas take the first character of publication and the other colums are displayed as unamed.

Comment: Unable to reproduce.

Comment: maybe you read different file then you expect - maybe first check `print( open(file_name).read() )` to see what you really read from file.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can first try to open the csv file using Microsoft Excel (or similar apps). This is to validate the file is a valid csv file.
2. Then you can try something like (assume you are using pandas 1.3.0+)

   pd.read_csv(file_name, sep=',', encoding='utf-8', encoding_errors='ignore')

More possible parameters: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Excel in my opinion is actually rather terrible with CSV files. Stick to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a problem you have but when I tried to replicate this I started to have some problems loading in the file so I had to add double `\\` instead of single `\`.

So the new path looks like
`file_name = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\Results.csv"`

Other than that, I was unable to replicate the issue you describe.